# Security - How to prevent XSS filename injection in Dropzone.js?

Tags: javascript, security, xss, dropzone.js

I am doing some security tests with my dropzone.js extension, I find out that it's possible with a Linux system to rename a legit filename and execute it with special characters like :

```
 "><svg onload=alert(1)>.jpg
```

or

```
 "><img src=x onerror=prompt(document.domain)>.png
```

This script injections are inoffensive, but some other could do great damage.  [we can find more examples on owasp.org](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Stored_Cross_site_scripting_(OTG-INPVAL-002))

To protect my filename I'm able to rename it via PHP with this :

```
       public static function FileTitleSafe($string)  {
   $str = $string;

   // Trim white spaces at beginning and end of title
   $str = trim($str);

   // Remove any duplicate whitespace, and XSS protect
   $str = preg_replace('/([\s\s]|\<|\>\=|\#|\"|\?|\%|\!|\*|\:|\.)+/', ' ', $str);
   // Trim dashes at beginning and end of alias
   $str = trim($str, '-');

   return $str;
  }
```

But it doesn't prevent the creation of filename in the thumbnail description...

How can I prevent the upload of unauthorized filename via a Dropzone Script by blocking non-legit characters or by renaming the filename before it appears in the thumbnail description?

Comment: I think you’re going about this the wrong way. All these file names are fine, albeit not entirely usual. What you should be doing is escaping them before printing them to the “thumbnail description”. In PHP you do this using `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: If the thumbnail description is client-side, set the `textContent` of an element, not the `innerHTML`, then you’ll be protected as well.

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert For the php part, you're right it could be better, maybe `string_tags` is better than `htmlspecialchars` or `preg_replace` in this case string `strip_tags ( string $str [, string $allowable_tags ] ) ` http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strip-tags.php 

What do you think?

Comment: `strip_tags` is notoriously broken for anything close to what you try to protect against (`onload` attributes and the like). If the user input is HTML, use a proper sanitizer like http://htmlpurifier.org/. If the user input is text, always escape with `htmlspecialchars`, this way, you’re always on the safe side.